# malloc: corrupted top size can not figure out the problem

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to write a simple C program that receives matrix (its size first) and inverts it, so I wrote some code, compile it, run and get a 'malloc: corrupted top size' error for matrices with size greater than 2. I checked code for unfreed memory, but I just do not see where I messed up.

The code itself:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

double det(double **matrix, int n, int m);
int invert(double **matrix, int n, int m);

int input(double ***matrix, int *n, int *m);
void output(double **matrix, int n, int m);

double **allocate_matrix(int n, int m);

int main(void) {
    double **matrix;
    int n, m;
    if (input(&matrix, &n, &m) == 0 && invert(matrix, n, m) == 0) {
        output(matrix, n, m);
        free(matrix);
    } else
        printf("n/a");
    return 0;
}

// Secondary functions

void swap(void *a, void *b, size_t size) {
    void *c = malloc(size);
    memcpy(c, a, size);
    memcpy(a, b, size);
    memcpy(b, c, size);
    free(c);
}

// Matrix allocation

double **allocate_matrix(int n, int m) {
    double **matrix = malloc(n * m * sizeof(double) + n * sizeof(double *));
    double *data = (double *)(matrix + n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) matrix[i] = data + m * i;
    for (int i = 0; i < n * m; i++) data[i] = 0;
    return matrix;
}

// Matrix operations

void matrix_for_det(double **matrix, int n, int m, double **res, int y, int x) {
    int in = 0, jn = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i == y) continue;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (j == x) continue;
            res[in][jn] = matrix[i][j];
            jn++;
        }
        in++;
    }
}

void matrix_const_mul(double **matrix, int n, int m, double c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] *= c;
        }
    }
}

double det(double **matrix, int n, int m) {
    if (n != m) return NAN;
    if (n == 2) return matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1] - matrix[0][1] * matrix [1][0];
    if(n == 1) return matrix[0][0];
    double result = 0;
    double **next = allocate_matrix(n - 1, m - 1);
    if (next != NULL) {
        for (int col = 0; col < m; col++) {
            matrix_for_det(matrix, n, m, next, 0, col);
            double atom = matrix[0][col] * det(next, n - 1, m - 1);
            if (col % 2 == 0)
                result += atom;
            else
                result -= atom;
        }
        free(next);
    } else
        result = NAN;
    return result;
}

int transpose(double ***matrix, int *n, int *m) {
    int exit_status = 0;
    double **result = allocate_matrix(*m, *n);
    if (result != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < *m; j++) {
                result[j][i] = (*matrix)[i][j];
            }
        }
        free(*matrix);
        *matrix = result;
        swap(n, m, sizeof(int));
    } else
        exit_status = -1;
    return exit_status;
}

int invert(double **matrix, int n, int m) {
    int exit_status = 0;
    double **new = allocate_matrix(n, m);
    double **next = allocate_matrix(n - 1, m - 1);
    if (new != NULL && next != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                matrix_for_det(matrix, n, m, next, i, j);
                new[i][j] = det(next, n - 1, m - 1);
                if ((i + j) % 2 == 1) new[i][j] *= -1;
            }
        }
        free(next);

        if (transpose(&new, &n, &m) == 0) {
            double det_v = det(matrix, n, m);
            matrix_const_mul(new, n, m, 1. / det_v);

            memcpy(matrix[0], new[0], n * m * sizeof(double));
        } else
            exit_status = -1;

        free(new);
    } else {
        if (new) free(new);
        if (next) free(next);
    }
    return exit_status;
}

// Input Output

int check_string() {
    int exit_status = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && exit_status == 0) {
        if (!isspace(c)) exit_status = -1;
    }
    return exit_status;
}

int input(double ***matrix, int *n, int *m) {
    int exit_status = 0;
    if (scanf("%d %d", n, m) == 2 && *n > 0 && *n == *m) {
        *matrix = allocate_matrix(*n, *m);
        for (int i = 0; i < *n && exit_status == 0; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < *m && exit_status == 0; j++) {
                if (scanf("%lf", (*matrix)[i] + j) != 1) exit_status = -1;
            }
        }
        exit_status += check_string();
        if (exit_status != 0) free(*matrix);
    } else
        exit_status = -1;
    return exit_status;
}

void output(double **matrix, int n, int m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m - 1; j++) {
            printf("%.6lf ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        if (m > 0) printf("%.6lf", matrix[i][m - 1]);
        if (i < n - 1) puts("");
    }
}
```

I tried using debug to see where something goes wrong, but it tells me that in `allocate_matrix()` function called from `transpose()` in `result` initialize malloc aborts. I do not understand why doesn't it return NULL like on internal error, but aborts all the program.

Comment: On first sight it's too complicated. You have `input()` two dimensions, but then say they must be the same: a square matrix.

Comment: What did Valgrind (or whatever memory checker you prefer) tell you?  That's usually the first port of call for investigating such problems.

Comment: @andrey-dru-mel, Note that `malloc(n * m * sizeof(double) + n * sizeof(double *))` can`int` overflows in cases where the preferred `malloc(sizeof(double) * n * m + n * sizeof(double *))` does not.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76936608/malloc-corrupted-top-size-can-not-figure-out-the-problem#comment135629009_76936608) Yeah, I know, but I have some kind of data entry requirements ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, aren't C variables converted automatically to the largest type presented?

Comment: @andrey-dru-mel "converted automatically to the largest type" --> yes, but in _pairs_.  With `int * int * size_t` the `int * int` is done first using `int` math _then_ the `int` product is multiplied by `size_t` using `size_t` math.  Consider `4000000 * 1000 * sizeof(double)` overflows (4000000 * 1000 is too big) whereas `sizeof(double) * 4000000 * 1000` does not. (Assume `size_t` is 8-byte).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, got it. It completes computations sequantially, step by step. This is not like math, which fact I did not take into account. But I will from now, thanks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem with the `matrix_for_det` function because it accesses `res` out of bounds. You initialize `jn` at the wrong place so `jn` will continue to increase well beyond the limit of `m-1`.

Fixed:

```c
void matrix_for_det(double **matrix, int n, int m, double **res, int y, int x) {
    int in = 0;                          // don't initialize `jn`  here
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i == y) continue;
        int jn = 0;                      // initialize `jn` here
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (j == x) continue;
            res[in][jn] = matrix[i][j];
            jn++;
        }
        in++;
    }
}
```

... or do the initialization in the `for` loops *init-clauses*.

```
void matrix_for_det(double **matrix, int n, int m, double **res, int y, int x) {
    for (int i = 0, in = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i == y) continue;
        for (int j = 0, jn = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (j == x) continue;
            res[in][jn] = matrix[i][j];
            jn++;
        }
        in++;
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG. Thanks a lot, mistake is so stupid, as always. I need to improve my debugging skills :)

Comment: @andrey-dru-mel You're welcome. Compile with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` if you use gcc or clang. It gives great help with problems like this. Also note chux's answer below which points out an important finding.

Answer (score 2):

Code has various issues, one not pointed out so far:

**Alignment**

OP's attempt to allocate *once* risks undefined behavior.

```
double **matrix = malloc(n * m * sizeof(double) + n * sizeof(double *));
double *data = double *data = (double *)(matrix + n);;  // Maybe UB
```

Consider the case when `double *` needs to point to an 8-byte aligned address since the target object is a `double` and `double **` points to a 4-byte aligned address since that target object is a *pointer*.

When `n` is odd, `(matrix + n)` is a 4-byte aligned value and casting that to `double *` leads to *undefined behavior* (UB).

A better approach allocates and assigns taking into account that padding may need to exist between `matrix[n-1]` and `data`.

---

IMO, just do 2 allocations.

If still wanting to do one allocation, do *something* like

```
// Illustrative code
size_t row_size = sizeof(double*) * n;
size_t padding = 0;
size_t alignment = alignof(double);
if (row_size % alignment > 0) {
  padding = alignment - row_size % alignment;
}
size_t data_size = sizeof(double) * n * m;  // Note the order to reduce overflow risk.
double **matrix = malloc(row_size + padding + data_size);
if (matrix) {
  double *data = (double *)((char *)matrix + row_size + padding);
```

The above could be done more elegantly, but its a hot August afternoon.  Time for some refreshment.

Comment: I had somewhere saw this memory allocation case and it felt to me as mockery on typification as a concept, but I couldn't explain why may it be a bad decision. So... That's why. Thanks for the tip, it is helpful :)